# When did dueling with weapons become socially unacceptable in the western world?

Tags: weapons, social-history, social-class

Now in the modern days, the phrase "lets settle this like men" would imply a fist fight. Yet as little as 200 years ago, "settling it like men" would either involve swords or pistols; the fist was the tool of the peasants and the lower class. When and how did it become socially unacceptable to use weapons to 'settle' accounts?

Comment: Related: http://history.stackexchange.com/q/9361/961

Comment: 50 years ago, 'taking it outside' was generally acceptable in the USA, with fisticuffs. If you were a 'gentleman' you boxed. If not, you might 'fight dirty'. It was the social norm and barring cases of serious injury or death, police, lawsuits etc. were not involved. I saw it many times and had occasion a few times to engage in such activity myself. It was nothing. Do you mean to include fists as weapons in your question? Not clear to me.

Comment: The Marquis of Queensbury can accept responsibility for moving fists from the peasant domain to polite society.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I think you mean the [**Marquess** of **Queensberry**?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquess_of_Queensberry_Rules)  Same rank; British version.

Comment: @MT_Head: Thank you; the Marquess was a better light-weight than I am, so I am glad you spotted that before he did.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Sorry to be That Guy, but I was just reading about him (the Marquess, not That Guy) and couldn't resist. The 9th Marquess seems to have been a real piece of work - hounded Oscar Wilde to his downfall; apparently syphilitic himself; really, really unfortunate in his relationships with his sons. If it weren't for the boxing and the atheism, I don't think I'd have a single good word to say about him.

Comment: In the British House of Commons the front benches are spaced slightly more than two sword lengths apart so that if someone from the opposite bench came at you you had a chance to draw your sword and defend yourself

Comment: @PurplePilot source? sounds interesting if true

Comment: It seems to me, but I have no research to confirm this, that duelling became illegal before it became socially unacceptable. And the reason for this is that guns became better, and people started to die more often during the duels, and the state didn't much like the upper classes killing each other.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because this is something that will vary greatly depending on various legal systems, locations, cultures, etc. Each country, or perhaps even each town or neighborhood might have its own unwritten laws about such things. "The Western World" is VERY LARGE and there is nothing to support the idea that at some point the entire 'Wester World' spontaneously decided that dueling was "out".

Answer (score 5):

France seems to hung on to the tradition longer than other places. It was still occurring in France with regularity before ww1. Perhaps it the slaughter of ww1 brought about the sharp decline after the war.

Georges Clemenceau french leader during war fought duels 
1892,duelled the author and Boulangist Paul Déroulède with pistols.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel#Decline
The last duel in France took place in 1967 when Gaston Defferre insulted René Ribière (fr) at the French parliament and was subsequently challenged to a duel fought with swords.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_famous_duels#French_duels
 February 1897: Marcel Proust fought journalist Jean Lorrain, after Lorrain published an excoriating review of Proust's first book "Pleasures and Days" and hinted that Proust was having an affair with Madame Alphonse Daudet's son, Lucien.

Comment: It's interesting to note that at the Height of the French duelling craze in the 17th century over 10000 people are estimated to have been killed - many as double or triple kills (Source - SPADA 2: Anthology of Swordsmanship)